# I want to rename a directory in magento and set the new refrence in the links

Tags: html, code, page

[image]

I want to rename this sns_tornoto to some thing else how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a design package. To rename it, follow these steps:

1. Rename skin/frontend/sns_tornoto
2. Rename app/design/frontend/sns_tornoto
3. In the admin panel go to *System > Configuration > Design* and change the package name from "sns_tornoto" to the new value.